TwinCat3 FBs/PRGs/GVLs
I just started programming with TwinCat v3 OOP.
I’m currently working on a warehouse that has several conveyors, they all have the same functionality to transport materials.
I was wondering what would be the best architecture to avoid GVLs. I have created FBs for conveyance and sensors but not sure how to linked them without using GVLs.
I have conveyors 1, conveyor 2 and conveyor 3 running in one PRG and Photo Sensor1-3 running on another program.
If I instance these conveyors locally I won’t be able to access them from the sensor program and viceversa.
Could interfaces work for this? Researching about interface at the moment but not sure if this will work. Maybe I will have many instance of interfaces…..

could you provide us some code to understand how are you working? in a FB you can define inputs and outputs that you can link to sensors, you do not need a global variable there

What exactly do you mean by "If I instance these conveyors locally"?

I like to create structure for physical IO and use %I %O only inside FBs that access EtherCAT data (non IO stuff, axis etc...). I would then create the function blocks with generic inputs and outputs and pass the data from that structure when calling the instance. That provides easy debugging and easy look at IO wiht a single glance at the variable names. Works for me and I sticked with it for years now.

With the function blocks
FUNCTION_BLOCK Conveyor
VAR_INPUT
    VarInA : BOOL;
END_VAR

FUNCTION_BLOCK Sensor
VAR_OUTPUT
    VarOutB : BOOL;
END_VAR

and the programs
PROGRAM PRG1
VAR
    Sensor1 : Sensor;
END_VAR

PROGRAM PRG2
VAR
    Conveyor1 : Conveyor;
END_VAR

you can use the following to connect your signals inside PRG2:
Conveyor1.VarInA := PRG1.Sensor1.VarOutB;


Instead of using VAR_INPUT and VAR_OUTPUT in the function blocks, you may as well use popertys with the according get() or set() implementations.
